# PayPal Chained Payment PHP

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm looking at setting up a PayPal chained payment request but I'm struggling right at the start (doesn't look good) haha.

Basically I'm using these API docs: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/

I'm just wondering where I get the APi details from? With the .developer console you don't get the signature or at least I can't find it.

Can anyone give me any examples of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this link](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run) to easily obtain API user, pass, and signature.

You might also be interested in taking a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It will make the API calls very simple for you.

Comment: Hi @Andrew I'm just looking at your examples now and I've noticed inside the pay-chain.php it has 2 receivers - PRIMARY and 2 secondary receivers.

If I only want 1 secondary receiver can I just delete the other one? Will this break your code?

Comment: Hey Andrew - I'm trying to use your package within Laravel but I'm struggling to get it to work correctly... can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, you can just remove the receive you don't need.  The sample is just showing how you would add additional receivers.

Comment: If you want to [post a ticket here](http://www.angelleye.com/support) I can help you more directly.  I've got a queue I need to get through, but I can get back to you ASAP.

Comment: You might want to take a look at my [PayPal Glass](http://paypal-glass.angelleye.com) project, which is done in Laravel and [available on GitHub](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-glass).